# Can't seem to find reason for infinite loop in SP

Tags: while-loop, sql-server-2012

This may be obvious for someone, but I cant seem to find a reason for an infinite loop in the following sql server stored procedure code. I also attached the flowchart. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    while (1 = 1)
    begin
       if condition1
       begin
          some statements
          break
       end
       else
       begin
          if condition2
          begin
             some statements
             break
          end
          else
          begin
             some statements modifying condition1 expression
             continue
          end
       end
    end
```

[image]

Comment: wouldn't 1 always equal 1? meaning, it would just loop through infinitely..

Comment: what condition did you want to test against there?

Comment: The condition checks the data in the string segment and if true then it reads it; if not it looks if any additional segments are present; if yes, it removes current segment and checks the next one.

Comment: wouldn't break statements take you out of loop under any circumstances?

Comment: yes, but what's in the while loop? here it's 1=1 which will always = true. You need to replace the while 1 = 1 to something else - something you're testing against.

Comment: I'm wondering why you're using a while loop to begin with if all you want to do is go through the case once anyway...

Comment: i wouldn't use it in the first place, but the reason behind it - the number of repeating segments that may come in is varying, so the loop needs to be adjusted dynamically. having 1=1 with break statements supposed to handle this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code actually worked after I eliminated temp variables that were used solely for reference convenience. To wribit and Angular Harsh: you can use while (1=1) to make your loop dynamic, you just need to use break statements.

Answer (score 0):

While(1=1) will lead to infinite loop. Please change that.

Comment: I'm aware that 1=1 is always true and it leads to infinite loop - BUT you can exit out of it with the break statement - and that is what i'm using in the code